# File is not a zip file error despite pandas older version

Tags: python, pandas, openpyxl, xlsxwriter

I'm having some troubles to write and read into an excel file. I'm aware of the changes in newest versions of openpyxl that other topics in here suggested (only XLS files by now) but stil I can't figure it out how to run my code.

I have two PCs and in one of them I have the exact same version of Python (3.8.2) and Pandas (1.0.1) and I can't run the code on the newest PC due to error: `BadZipFile: File is not a zip file`.

Here is what I'm trying to do:

```
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='xlsxwriter')
totalDF.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace('.',',')).to_excel(writer, sheet_name=sheet, startrow=0 , startcol=0)
workbook = writer.book

if indSPE == 0:
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
    worksheet.set_column(0, 0, 11)
    worksheet.set_column(1, 1, 25)
    worksheet.set_column(2, 2, 12)
    worksheet.set_column(3, 3, 25)
    worksheet.set_column(4, 4, 20)
    worksheet.write('G2', str(piranomsComProblema))
    
else:
    book = load_workbook(fileName)
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fileName, engine='openpyxl') 
    writer.book = book
    writer.sheets = dict((ws.title, ws) for ws in book.worksheets)
    totalDF.applymap(lambda x: str(x).replace('.',',')).to_excel(writer, sheet)
    worksheet = writer.sheets[sheet]
    worksheet.column_dimensions['A'].width = 11
    worksheet.column_dimensions['B'].width = 25
    worksheet.column_dimensions['C'].width = 12
    worksheet.column_dimensions['D'].width = 25
    worksheet.column_dimensions['E'].width = 20
    worksheet.cell(row=2, column=7).value = str(piranomsComProblema)
    

workbook.close()

writer.save()
writer.close()
```

The problem is in the second time that I'll open the file and write on it. The first time it enters the loop, it runs normally, but after that it crashes. Any ideas on how to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Edit:
To specify a bit more, the problem is specificly in line `book = load_workbook(fileName)` and the `fileName` variable is a xlsx file.

Comment: Please include the complete traceback so it's clear **what** is not working. My guess, from your comment below which makes clear the code is incomplete, is that you're overwriting the file.

Answer (score 0):

The error suggests that you are not trying to load a file that is in *.xslx format (which in fact is a bunch of files compressed with zip). It can be that the path to the file is wrong (`fileName`) or that the format of an existing file is problematic.

Did you debug into this line and checked if the file actually exist and you can decompress it after changing the extension to ".zip"?

Comment: Hey, thank you for your effort! Yes, it saves the file normally as a xlsx format for the first time. If I remove the for loop and only run it once, it creates the file as expected and I can open it normally. The problem really is when I try to open it again to input more data